# How to log contents of dataframe so same contents is not printed each time program is run?

Tags: python, pandas, logging

I need to keep a log of the contents of my dataframe so the same content is not printed over and over. The python program loop runs continuously so I need the dataframe to contain only information which is new when I print it.

Loop 1 of python program:

```
r = requests.get('URL')
data = []
for selection in r.json['selections]:
        data.append('selection['name'])
print(data)
['Which Lily', 'All Star Rocket', 'Cold Powder']
cols1 = ['Horse']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols1)
```

Loop 2 of python program:

```
r = requests.get('URL')
data = []
for selection in r.json['selections]:
        data.append('selection['name'])
print(data)
['Which Lily', 'All Star Rocket', 'Cold Powder','Coming Around','Winx']
cols1 = ['Horse']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols1)
```

Desired output on Loop 2 of python program:

```
['Coming Around','Winx']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a track of all the names which you have already received. It will help you not to append the names in the data list if the name is already present

Use a global dictionary to keep track of the names received like below

```
data_log = {}
r = requests.get('URL')
data = []
for selection in r.json['selections]:
  if data_log.get(selection['name'], 0) == 0:
    data_log[selection['name']] = 1
    data.append(selection['name'])
print(data)


cols1 = ['Horse']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols1)
```

**The output of the 1st iteration:**

`['Which Lily', 'All Star Rocket', 'Cold Powder']`

**The output of the 2nd iteration:**

`['Coming Around', 'Winx']`

Comment: if datalog.get(selection['name'],0) == 0 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'. I don't think you are able to use the get function to retrieve data from the datalog.

Comment: I also had to combine some code as there were indentation errors. if datalog([selection['name']],0) == 0 and datalog[selection['name']] == 1:

Comment: Your error suggests you have made data_log a list. Make it a dictionary

Comment: Also, make a habit to post minimum reproducible code when you post on StackOverflow to avoid indentation error.